# SQL query to Identify and then delete all except latest record

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have the following query which identifies duplicate records based on the employee_id field.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c1.employee_id ORDER BY c1.lastlogon ASC ) AS Row
    ,[DN]
    ,[first_name]
    ,[last_name]
    ,[init]
    ,[email]
    ,[title]
    ,[display_name]
    ,[department]
    ,[phone_num]
    ,[mob_num]
    ,[fax_num]
    ,[pager_num]
    ,[logon]
    ,[post_code]
    ,[www]
    ,[objectSID]
    ,[disabled]
    ,[lastlogon]
    ,[employee_id]
    ,[acc_type]
FROM AD_Users_All_Staging c1
WHERE EXISTS
(
     SELECT 1
     FROM AD_Users_All_Staging c2
     WHERE c2.employee_id = c1.employee_id
     GROUP BY 
         employee_id
     HAVING COUNT(1) > 1  -- more than one value
)
```

How do a select just the latest record (values in lastlogon field) for which as duplicate exists (values in employee_id field)

The follow up question is how do I delete the all the records for each duplicate apart from the latest record?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have your data, I can't try anything easily... But, that said, what if you changed the windowing function to use `c.lastlogon Desc` instead of **Asc**. Then, you would always keep the first record `Row = 1` and delete the rest `Row > 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the latest record using:

```
select uas.*
from AD_Users_All_Staging uas
where not exists (select 1
                  from AD_Users_All_Staging uas2
                  where uas2.employee_id = uas.employee_id and
                        uas2.lastlogon > uas.lastlogon
                 );
```

You can do the `delete` using inverse logic:

```
select uas.*
from AD_Users_All_Staging uas
where exists (select 1
              from AD_Users_All_Staging uas2
              where uas2.employee_id = uas.employee_id and
                    uas2.lastlogon > uas.lastlogon
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some head scratching:

I've tried this and it looks like it gives me the results it needs:

```
;WITH cte AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c1.employee_id ORDER BY c1.lastlogon DESC) AS Row
    ,[DN]
    ,[first_name]
    ,[last_name]
    ,[init]
    ,[email]
    ,[title]
    ,[display_name]
    ,[department]
    ,[phone_num]
    ,[mob_num]
    ,[fax_num]
    ,[pager_num]
    ,[logon]
    ,[post_code]
    ,[www]
    ,[objectSID]
    ,[disabled]
    ,[lastlogon]
    ,[employee_id]
    ,[acc_type]
FROM AD_Users_All_Staging c1
WHERE EXISTS
(
     SELECT 1
     FROM AD_Users_All_Staging c2
     WHERE c2.employee_id = c1.employee_id
     GROUP BY 
         employee_id
     HAVING COUNT(1) > 1  -- more than one value
)
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE row != 1
```

Does this look ok?

Comment: Sure, that is basically what I was suggesting.